# while increasing height particular row of data grid view affecting last row also

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

in my grid view i am checking wethar 6th column of grid view having image,,if having image then i am increasing that particular row size,,so i wrote code like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= gv.Rows.Count - 1; i++) {
    if (!Information.IsDBNull(gv.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value)) {
        gv.Rows(i).Height = 75;
        DataGridViewColumn column = gv.Columns(6);
        column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
    }
}
```

this time my last row of data grid view also getting the row height 75..i dont want to do that.

Comment: do your last row has an image?

Comment: in data grid view we always get the last row(for adding new record) am talking about that row

Comment: if you want i can show my data grid view image

Comment: is your `Information.IsDBNull` is checking whether the column has image?

Comment: no sir,,that s not working porper?

Comment: if you want to disable your last row, then set the `AllowUserToAddRows` property of your datagridview equal to false;

Comment: i dont want to disable,becouse i want to add new data s,,sir how i can check whether the column has image

Comment: Is your gridview loading images from any datasource? If it is, then you can check it while you are loading data in gridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the for loop change the **<=** to **<**

`for (int i = 0; i < gv.Rows.Count - 1; i++)`

Comment: this is not the solution. if the last row has an image, what will happen then?

Comment: @AbdurRahim last row means data grid view always show one row for adding new records